# Streamline these if statements and output them with their values

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a way that I can streamline my process when I'm working with theme options on Wordpress?

Currently I use a setup like this when I'm creating a social links menu for example (With the option value being the link URL);

```
$twitter = of_get_option('twitter');
$facebook = of_get_option('facebook');
$google-plus = of_get_option('google-plus');

if ($twitter){
    echo '<li class="twitter"><a href="'.$twitter.'"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>';
}
if ($facebook){
    echo '<li class="facebook"><a href="'.$facebook.'"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>';
}
if ($google-plus){
    echo '<li class="google-plus"><a href="'.$google-plus.'"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>';
}
```

I'm sure there must be an easier, more streamlined, way to go about doing this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Switch? Make a switch function and pass the options in as a parameter?(add more if that's the case). I dunnp, something like that, I guess...

Comment: It should be noted that `of_get_option()` is specific to the `options framework` and not `wordpress` in general.

Answer (score 0):

I'd wrapp it in a function.

```
function getOption($op) {
    $link = of_get_option($op);
    if($link)
        echo '<li class="'.$op.'"><a href="'.$link.'"><i class="fa fa-'.$op.'"></i></a></li>';
}

getOption('twitter');
getOption('facebook');
getOption('google-plus');
```